# Scrapy problem with clicking data and next URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm currently working on a spider that inputs a TICKER symbol into a search bar after logging in with email and password.

In a regular state, once after logging in, searching in the search bar and pressing enter will redirect the user to the dashboard of the specific ticker. The URL has nothing that resembles the TICKER entered, only numbers. Meaning I cannot give Scrapy the next URL- it is based on the ticker.

I couldn't find any correlation between the numbers and the TICKER,

I tried entering the TICKER with form request and then asking for the response URL, but it didn't work.

```js
ticker = 'save'
formdata={'ctrlHeader_searchBar_txtSearch': ticker}
yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='form1', formdata=formdata, callback=self.open_ticker,clickdata={'id': 'ctrlHeader_searchBar_hiddenControl'})
yield scrapy.http.Request(response.url, callback=self.open_browser)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What spider are you referring to? Please clarify your question.

Comment: hey Erich, I have solved the problem, the spider i was referring to was a scrapy spider scraping a financial web. The problem was that after you enter a ticker in the website the next url depends on a number generated by the ticker itself. what I did (and needed to do) was to extract the url from the next button and make a request with that specific url.